# One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version - Facebook-auth

Tags: flutter, firebase, facebook-android-sdk

Good work, I decided to write facebook login for my app. I used this package `flutter_facebook_auth: ^5.0.6`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDlsU.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzaAA.png)

I changed the sdk version to 33 but the error persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with the last version:

In **android/app/build.gradle** you have to modify **compileSdkVersion** line in android{} to:

```
compileSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.compileSdkVersion').toInteger()
```

and in **android/local.properties** you have to add this line if it doesn't exist:

```
flutter.compileSdkVersion= 33
```

EDITED----

And for the **minSdkVersion**

**android/local.properties:**
flutter.minSdkVersion=16

**android/app/build.gradle:**

> inside defaultConfig{}:

`minSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion').toInteger()`

Comment: another eror about ```uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 18 declared in library [:flutter_secure_storage] C:\Users\ASUS\ilkvisual\build\flutter_secure_storage\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
 Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
  or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 18,
  or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.it_nomads.fluttersecurestorage" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.```

Comment: In local.properties also add flutter.minSdkVersion=16

Comment: and in build.gradle inside defaultConfig{}: minSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion').toInteger()

Answer (score 0):

check your android/app/build.gradle and add this on android side

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    }
```